# Custom BitmapSource with dynamic content

Tags: wpf

I would like to implement a custom BitmapSource class that provides an image that changes occasionally. How does a BitmapSource signal to its consumers that the image has changed and must be reloaded?

For example, consumers of a WritableBitmap update after AddDirtyRect is called. I would like to create a similar mechanism in my BitmapSource class.

An equivalent question is: how can a consumer of an ImageSource know that the image has changed and should be re-loaded?

Comment: You may use JetBrains dotPeek to take a look at the WriteableBitmap sources in the PresentationCore assembly.

Comment: Did you check the class [DrawableImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.drawingimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. WPF handles this internally by sending a DUCE.MILCMD_BITMAP_INVALIDATE command. It is not possible for an application to send or receive this command.

There is some information and example code about writing a custom BitmapSource at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dwayneneed/2008/06/20/implementing-a-custom-bitmapsource/

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround I've used to do this.

1. Create `ImageProvider` class that inherits from `DependencyObject` or `INotifyPropertyChanged` with read only `ImageSource` property that you fill in.
2. Put the instance of this provider in resources of your `Window`/`Control` like this:

`<Window>
   <Window.Resources>
       <controls:MyImageProvider x:Key="Provider" />
   </Window.REsources>
</Window>`

3. Bind your image to the `ImageSource` property on your provider:

`<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource, Source={StaticResource Provider}" />`

4. Everytime you want to refresh the image, set the `ImageSource` property on your provider, and let WPF handle the update.